# How to access Github NPM Private package with SSH config?

Tags: node.js, github, npm, github-packages

I have created and published a NPM Private Package to github packages.  To access it in package.json I had to add

```
"@orgname/package-name": "1.1.1"
```

I have also created .npmrc file which contains following lines. Note: `NPM_TOKEN` is set with envirinment variable.

```
@orgname:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

I can also access `"@orgname/package-name": "1.1.1"` if i login to npm with my personal access token in with this way.

```
$ npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

As I am using github and I can access repository by setting my ssh key. I was hoping to know if it is possible to access private npm package without creating any extra token.